# 2 JQuery menus conflicting

Tags: jquery, include, conflict

I have 2 JQuery navigation menus.

My main navigation (navig.php) uses the following JQuery scripts:

```
<script src='/new/navig/js/jquery-1.8.1.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='/new/navig/jquery.kwicks.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

My sub menu (menu.php) uses the following JQuery scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/new/menu/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/new/menu/sliding_effect.js"></script>
```

I have little knowledge of this subject, but seeing as both these navigations are included in all pages, do i have to declare the JQuery at the start of every page? If so what scripts do i delete in these pages?

**EDIT: I moved the  first script from each page to the index.php where the includes are pulled to. The menu.php still worked fine however the navig.php did not (same as before). However the script in the navig.php is being declared in the body just before it is used and does not work anywhere else.**

Is there way to overcome the conflict or do i need to find another menu?

Thanks!

Comment: don't include jQuery library twice

Answer (score 0):

Yes, browser need all scripts you are using in a page everytime. If you have a master page concept you could include all globally used scripts and css there. If you have page specific scripts that can be specified in the page itself.

Also you could think about bundling commonly used script/css files.

Comment: But surely if i include all scripts in a global page they are still going to conflict?

Comment: is jquery.js contains your custom scripts. if its jquery lib, then you don't require that as you are using jquery-1.8.1.min.js in master page.